# NumberFormatException overridden by else statement

Tags: java, exception

So the issue I have here is that my `NumberFormatException` is overridden by my `else` statement therefore it is not being 'called' whenever a string is passed by and returning number of arguments invalid instead.

```
public class Ex4 {
      public static void main(String[] args) {


  try{
      if(args.length == 1){
          double temp = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
          System.out.println(temp);
        } else if(args.length == 2){
              double temp = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
              double temp1 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
              System.out.println(temp * temp1);
        } else if(args.length == 3){
             double temp = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
             double temp1 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
             double temp2 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
             System.out.println(temp * temp1 * temp2);    
        } else {
            System.out.println("number of arguments invalid");
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("invalid operation");
    }
 }}
```

So my question is, how can I still use `NumberFormatException` and check that the values passed through `args` is of a valid value?

Edit: I can remove the `else` which will trigger the catch statement, however what do I do in a situation that there are a number of arguments which are invalid?

Note: I do understand why it's failing however I do not know how to overcome this and have worked on it and continue to do so in the meantime, just any support would be great.

Edit2: People asking for inputs and resulting outputs:

- `java Ex4 3`             will print  `3.0`
- `java Ex4 3 2 2`         will print `12.0`
- `java Ex4 5 1`           will print `5.0`
- `java Ex4 A B C D`       will print the string `“invalid operation”`
- `java Ex4 3 2 2  5 6`    will print `”number of arguments invalid"`
- `java Ex4`               will print `”number of arguments invalid"`

Updated code for anyone in the future which works:

```
 public class Ex4 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  double temps[] = new double[args.length];
  boolean cont = true;
  try{
          for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
      temps[i] = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
    }
  } catch(NumberFormatException e){
      System.out.println("invalid operation");
      cont = false;
    }

        if(args.length == 1){
            System.out.println(temps[0]);
        } else if(args.length == 2){
            System.out.println(temps[0] * temps[1]);
        } else if(args.length == 3){
            System.out.println(temps[0] * temps[1] * temps[2]);
        } else if(args.length < 1 && cont == true || args.length > 3 && cont == true){
            System.out.println("number of arguments invalid");
        }  
    }
```

}

Comment: What is your input examples?

Comment: 3 will print  3.0 |||
3 2 2 will print 12.0 |||
5 1 will print 5.0 |||
A B C D will print the string “invalid operation”  |||
3 2 2  5 6 will print ”number of arguments invalid" |||
        will print ”number of arguments invalid" ||| @zahrul

Comment: This code could be much shorter if you used a for loop, by the way

Comment: @ToastAndJam allright. Now tell us what ouput you'd expect of this calls.

Comment: @cricket_007 agree, I like `switch(arg.length)` for logic that change based on the arguments length but here, a loop is godd.

Comment: @cricket any improvements that can be made to my code would be of great help, may I ask where you would apply this?

Comment: @ToastAndJam Nevermind, I missread. Am I guessing correctly that with input `A B C D` you WANT “invalid operation” but you GET ”number of arguments invalid"?

Comment: @andre YES!!! Can you help me with this please.

Comment: @ToastAndJam If accepting any number of arguments would be an acceptable solution, I suggest you rewrite this using a for-loop. I suggest you try this yourself first because it's a good exercise. If you have tried and can't get it to work, come back here and ask another question.

Comment: @AndréStannek That is definately my next step and will do. Overall, thanks for the support guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error condition before continuing.

```
if(args.length > 3 || args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("number of arguments invalid");
} else {
    double mult = 1.0;
    try {
        for (String arg : args) {
            mult *= Double.parseDouble(arg);
        } 
   } catch (...) { 
       // your message 
   } 
   System.out.println(mult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks from OP to do his `Ex4` ;)

Comment: There was an attempt provided, so it's not a pure homework dump

Comment: Thank you! I never thought about checking the error condition before moving onto the main part of the code. Thank you again.

Comment: I agree, I would provide the idea of improvment, not the code itself. That's all

Comment: @Toast it's always a good practice to catch invalid conditions early rather than assuming that user input is in a valid state and working around that

Comment: By the way, you should add some `...` for the catch block, as this is not a good idea to hide exceptions in general. But you have my vote.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown by `Double.parseDouble(String)`. If you don't call it, no exception can be thrown.

So you are actually checking if get enough arguments, which is good, with the if-else.

Then with the try-catch, you check if this is a valid number.

This is correct as it is.

Comment: So this means, I need to refrain from parsing it as a double until 'after' the if statement is completed and outside the try/catch statement?

Comment: @ToastAndJam That's your logic, that's up to you. But you would not know how many value to parse if you do it later. No, this is correct, not the best implementation but correct